# Spring Data: How to automatically remove a child relation when it is removed from the parent

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have a `User` entity that holds a `Character` entity in a `@OneToOne` relation. However I wantt he `Character` record to be removed as soon as it gets detached from the `User` entity.

Here is my `User.kt` entity class:

```kotlin
// User.kt

@Entity
class User(
    @Id
    var id: String,
    var email: String,
    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    var character: Character?,
    var isAdmin: Boolean
) { // ... }
```

This is the unit test I wrote to test this behaviour:

```kotlin
// UserRepositoryTest.kt

@Test
fun `should remove orphan character entity when being removed from user entity`() {
    val user = UserTestTemplate.testUser()
    val character = CharacterTestTemplate.testCharacter()

    user.character = character
    userRepository.save(user)

    user.character = null
    userRepository.save(user)

    val actual = userRepository.findById(user.id).orElse(null)

    assertThat(actual).isNotNull()
    assertThat(actual.character).isNull()

    val savedCharacter = characterRepository.findById(character.id)
    assertThat(savedCharacter.get()).isNull() // fails
}
```

I added the `CascadeType.ALL` and `orphanRemoval = true` option since those are the only things I read about being related to my request.

What I do in the unit test is creating a user and character instance. Then adding the character instance to the user and saving the user via the `UserRepository`. Thanks to `CascadeType.ALL` the character instance will be saved automatically. Now I'd like to have the same thing in reverse when *removing* the character from the user. This however does not work as expected as you can see in the last line of the unit test

Comment: Is it a bi-directional relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to be aware of:

- transactional write behind pattern
- first level cache

```java
@Test
fun `should remove orphan character entity  entity`() {
    val user = UserTestTemplate.testUser()
    val character = CharacterTestTemplate.testCharacter()

    user.character = character
    userRepository.save(user)

    user.character = null

    //use saveAndFlush here to force immediate DB update
    //otherwise may be deferred until transactional method returns
    userRepository.saveAndFlush(user)

    //clear the persistence context to ensure you will be reading from 
    //the database rather than first level cache
    //entityManager is injected to test via @PersistenceContext annotation
    entityManager.clear();

    //now you are guaranteed a db read reflecting all flushed updates
    val actual = userRepository.findById(user.id).orElse(null)

    assertThat(actual).isNotNull()
    assertThat(actual.character).isNull()

    val savedCharacter = characterRepository.findById(character.id)
    assertThat(savedCharacter.get()).isNull() // fails
}
```

Comment: do I need the `entityManager.clear()` and `.saveAndFlush` in the normal business logic as well or just for the sake of the unit test here?

Comment: While there may be reasons for forcing a flush or clearing the persistence context in normal business logic I would say that these are things you do not normally need to concern yourself with.